Login with SMAL ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2
I am using the library
Login with SMAL ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 to make a project that works with identity to authenticate user use SMAL to do so. The part of asking the person who accesses the system for username and password works, but when I try to recover the information of the user who has accessed I do not recover anything. missing? I attach code.
AuthController:
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Auth")]
public class AuthController : Controller
{                                       /*//ReturnUrl*/
    const string relayStateReturnUrl = "https://localhost:57200/"; 
    private readonly Saml2Configuration config;
    public AuthController(IOptions<Saml2Configuration> configAccessor)
    {
        config = configAccessor.Value;
    }
    //El punto final de inicio de sesión es donde el usuario no autenticado envía una solicitud cuando desea iniciar sesión
    [Route("Login")]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
        return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)).ToActionResult();
    }

    //El punto final SamlResponse es donde el usuario será redirigido nuevamente después de que Microsoft haya indicado que ingresó el nombre de usuario y la contraseña correctos y que inició sesión
    [Route("SamlResponse")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SamlResponse()
    {            
        var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
        var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);
        binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
        if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
        }
        binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
        await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext);
        return Redirect("https://localhost:57200");
    }       
}

_layout.cshtml
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
     var nameClaim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Type=="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname");
     var name = nameClaim == null ? null : nameClaim.Value;
 
      <span class="navbar-text">Hello,  @name!</span>
 }
 else
 {
     <a asp-controller="Auth" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
 }

Program.cs
//SMAL2

Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
builder.Services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(configuration.GetSection("Saml2"));
builder.Services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(saml2Configuration =>
{
    saml2Configuration.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(saml2Configuration.Issuer);
    string rootDirectory = configuration.GetValue<string>(WebHostDefaults.ContentRootKey);
    //var cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(rootDirectory + "/cert.cer");
    //saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.Add(cert);
    var entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor();
    entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(configuration["Saml2:IdPMetadata"]));
    if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor != null)
    {
        saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("IdPSsoDescriptor not loaded from metadata.");
    }
});
builder.Services.AddSaml2();

appsettings.json
"Saml2": {
  "IdPMetadata": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/01ec0a12-bbce-40b2-9f30-60c2bf9767c6/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=8fb79f36-51ed-4523-814b-640132aeb877",    
  "IdPMetadataFile": "XXXXX.xml",
  "Issuer": "XXXXXX",
  "SignatureAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256",
  "CertificateValidationMode": "None", //  "ChainTrust",
  "RevocationMode": "NoCheck",


You probably need to debug and see what is happing; if the SAML authn response is received by you app, and then go through the steps.
